# Saving dynamic list items efficiently

Tags: php, mysql

I have supermarkets stored in my database. For each supermarket, in an admin area the user can create a shopping list with products and keep track of the products by checking (= user has already bought the product) or unchecking them (= user still needs to buy the product). My question is how to efficiently store the shopping list items in MySQL?

My markup with example data:

```
<form>

   <h1>Supermarket: "City Store"</h1>

   <p>Create/edit your shopping list:</p>

   <ul id="shopping-list">
     <li><input type="text">Tomatoes</input> <input type="checkbox"></li> 
     <li><input type="text">Apples</input> <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></li> 
     <li><input type="text"></input> <input type="checkbox"></li> 
   </ul>

   <button id="add-list-item">Add list item</button>

   <button id="save-list-items">Save</button>

</form>

$('#add-list-item').on('click', function() { 
 $('#shopping-list').append('<li> <input type="text"></input><input type="checkbox"></li>');
});
```

In this scenario, when the user logs in, he sees that in the past he already added two products to the list, tomatoes and apples. As he already has bought apples, he had checked them. If he wants to add products, he can press the button.

In my MySQL environment I already have a table "supermarkets". For storing the shopping list items I want to create an additional table "shopping-list-items" with the following fields:

```
 - id
 - id_supermarket
 - content
 - status (1 = 'checked', 0 = 'still unchecked')
 - date_created
 - date_updated
 - date_checked
```

As you can see, I want the date of each list item being saved, for when it is being created, updated AND checked.

How can I send the data of the shopping list to my database via POST and distinguish between checked and unchecked items? I basically know how to send data via the name attribute to a database and to save them, but in this case I want to save each entry individually and at the same time consider the checkbox state and I have no idea how to handle that.